# Shell: Arithmetic expressions in case possible without setting a variable? Example inside, please help :)

Tags: shell, syntax

I am currently learning shell thanks to the Bash-Beginners-Guide provided by tldp.

Currently I am doing some exercises to improve my Shell scripting skills, in this case I am learning how to use if and case statements.

I have written some code and want to know if it is possible to use arithmetic expressions directly in case expressions without setting a variable beforehand like I did in my code.

Note that I don't want to have a solution for self-assigned 'homework', but rather get enlightenment in regard to syntax basics in Shell.

The code, free to use:

```
echo "Starting exercise 2..."
day=`date +%e`
year=`date +%Y`
echo "Number of days in this month: $day days"
echo "Calculating leap years:"
calc1=$[$year % 400]
case $calc1 in
0) echo "$leap";;
*) 
    calc2=$[$year % 100]
    case $calc2 in
        0) echo "$noleap" ;;
        *) 
            calc3=$[$year % 4]
            case $calc3 in
            0) echo "$leap" ;;
            *) echo "$noleap" ;;
        esac
esac
```

leap and noleap are just some Strings, they don't matter for my problem.

I want to get rid of those calc* vars and do something like:

```
case $[$year % 400] in
    0) echo "$noleap";;
    ...
```

Is this possible?

**Mind you that I am an ABSOLUTE beginner, I've started learning Shell 2 days ago.**

Edit: I think I answered my own question. Looks like

```
case $[arithmetic expression] in
```

works. However there is need in validation, yet.

Edit2: Fixed irrelevant error noleap -> leap in year%400 case.

Comment: Since you are a beginner, you might not want to hear this ... Michal's answer is better than `$[ ... ]` in the sense that it is standard and will work in many shells.  For example, both `bash` and `zsh` accept `$[]`, but ksh does not.  It's not something to be terribly worried about, but you should be aware that there are many non-standard extensions that bash uses.  Eventually, use of bashisms may come back to haunt you.

Comment: Why shouldn't I want to hear this? Better to hear about it and learn/correct myself than later when my brain does those things automatically. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: A lot of people complain loudly when issues of portability are brought up.  My opening phrase was an attempt to preemptively silence anyone who might like to respond by saying that portability is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try arithmetic expansion: `case $(($year%400)) in ...`. This syntax can be used almost anywhere that variable expansion can, including in double quotes.